# $(document).ready(function()) is not working in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$(document).ready(function())` is not working in my jsp.I have tried in many forms.

My code is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload Success</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquerymin.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("Hiiii"); 
});  
</script>
</head>
<body>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have read that !DOCTYPE declaration should be at top most. is that wrong?

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/8pgywcsg/

Comment: You have used jquery library multiple times, why? Remove that, just keep one.

Comment: And I'm trying to sleep but it's not working either.

Comment: Does alert work when you comment out the lines before and after?

Comment: Probably it's because of the encoding of your page `ISO-8859-1` while `jquery.js` is in UTF-8.

Comment: open script using chrome and go to console and check the error. maybe jquery doesn't load

Comment: You included jquery file multiple times and that may be the reason.

Comment: I have removed but not working

Comment: Can you check browse console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This... I have Tested, working fine....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload Success</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("Hiiiiii.........");  
});  
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have jquery included twice

Answer (score 1):

`$(Document).ready` is works when loaded JQuery library.
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Hello World!!!");  
});  
</script>
```